# PassportJS: serializeUser() Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am simply trying to serialise the user in passportjs following the "normal" flow. However I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

I don't understand where I could send the res since I am just using the middleware to send it. Here is how I call the authentication route:

```
routes.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-signup-sme', {
        successRedirect : req.get('origin') + '/dashboard', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : req.get('origin') + '/signupSME', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash    : true,
        successFlash    : 'User created !'
    })(req, res, next)
});
```

and here is my local-signup-sme, i only call done() and I only call it once, or in a callback, I have checked if there was any if without an else but I can't find any...

What am I doing wrong ?

```
 // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

 passport.use('local-signup-sme', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass in the req from our route (lets us check if a user is logged in or not)
    },
    function(req, _email, _password, done) {
        if (typeof _password === 'undefined' ){
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Password field is missing'})
        } else if( typeof _email === 'undefined'){
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Email field is missing'})
        } else {
            var password = bcrypt.hashSync(_password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)); //encrypt password and store the hash...
            var companySelected = JSON.parse(req.body.companySelected);
            if (!req.user) {
                checkCompanyRegistrationStatus(companySelected.company_number,
                    function(){
                        checkUserRegistrationStatus(_email,
                            function(){
                                checkPasswordStrength(_password,
                                    function(){
                                        maindb.MainDBInsert("INSERT INTO Uncomplete_Users_Registrations (first_name, last_name, password, email, company_registrat_number, company_name) OUTPUT Inserted.id VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);",
                                                    [req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName, password, _email, companySelected.company_number, companySelected.title],
                                                    function(user, rowsCount){
                                                        return done(null, user[0]);
                                                    },
                                                    function(code, err){
                                                        return done(null, false, {message:  err});
                                                    }
                                                );
                                            }, function (err) {
                                                return done(null, false, {message: err});
                                            })
                                    }, function(err){
                                        return done(null, false, {message: err})
                                    }
                                )

                            }, function(err){
                                return done(null, false, {message: err})
                            }
                        )
                    }, function(err){
                        return done(null, false, {message: err})
                    }
                )
            } else {
                // user is logged in and already has a local account. Ignore signup. (You should log out before trying to create a new account, user!)
                return done(null, req.user);
            }
        }
    }));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passport JS "Can't set headers after they are sent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557256/passport-js-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent)

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty I have looked at this, does not answer my question, in that question the user was manually redirecting, i am not, i am just using the middleware.

Comment: do you get the error regardless of whether the login credential were correct or wrong?

Comment: The credential are right by default since its right after the signup, i don't manually parse the credential, passport does it on its own during the successRedirect.