# passport.js throws Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have read other solutions, but those aren't working for me.

[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557256/passport-js-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent) This talks about using `else`, which I have already used.
[2] One other talks about using `return` with `done` which seems illogical because the docs don't mention using `return`

I have a page that I need to load regardless of whether a user is logged in or not. If the user is not logged in, I have to show a Login Button, otherwise a logout button.

This is the route where the error occurs:

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.query.code || req.cookie) { //either first time authenticating or already a user
        passport.authenticate('google')(req, res, next)
    }
    res.render('index', { user: req.user });
})
```

This is the route I hit when user hits login:

```
app.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile', 'email']
}));
```

This is my passport strategy setup:

```
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        callbackURL: `${process.env.address}`,
        clientID: `${process.env.GOOGLE_SSO_CLIENT_ID}`,
        clientSecret: `${process.env.GOOGLE_SSO_CLIENT_SECRET}`,

    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {

        if(accessToken) {
            User.findOne({email: profile.email}).then((currentUser) => {

                if(currentUser){ // already exists
                    console.log('user is: ', currentUser);
                    done(null, currentUser)
                    // do something
                } else { // if not, create user in our db
                    new User({
                        email: profile.email,
                        joinDate: Date.now(),
                        username: 'random'
                    }).save().then((newUser) => {
                        console.log('created new user: ', newUser);
                        done(null, newUser)
                        // do something
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            done(null, null)
        }
    })
)
```

The problem might be that I am trying to hit the URL where

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this would work you job?

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.query.code || req.cookie) { 
        passport.authenticate('google', function(req, res, next) {
           res.render('index', { user: req.user });
        });
    } else {
        res.render('index');
    }
})
```

Comment: Why use custom callback? Besides it looks like the method signature for a custom callback involves `err, user, info` instead of `req, res, next` http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/

Comment: take a look on last part of page [pasport/](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/google/)

Comment: If you are talking about the method, I think the `(req, res)` is used for `app.get()` and not. If you are talking about the custom callback, sorry I did not understand, can you elaborate?

Comment: Also, why did you add the repetitive `else`? I had thought of it before, but the result did not change.